# Encoding params of url that generated dynamically for use in CURL

Tags: php, curl, encode

I write a robot and fetch all URL in web page. the URLs is be like this:

```
http://www.example.com/result/رایانه
```

Now, When I try to fetch content of this url by CURL, give me this error:

```
400 Bad request
```

I know this cause because for `"رایانه"` in url and must encoding it.
But that URL is dynamically, and I need a solution for encode just params in URL.
Be like this:

```
"http://www.example.com/result/" . urlencode("رایانه")
```

Or another example:

Maybe I have this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/result/سوتی/?foo=علی&bar=حسن
```

If I use `urlencode()` return this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fresult%2F%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AA%DB%8C%2F%3Ffoo%3D%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%26bar%3D%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86
```

But so must just encode this words: `سوتی`, `علی`, `حسن`.
and have this correct encoded:

```
http://www.example.com/result/%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AA%DB%8C/?foo=%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C&bar=%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86
```

I need this for use in CURL.
How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I found this code:

```
echo implode("/", array_map("urlencode", explode("/", $string)));
```

return:

```
http%3A//www.example.com/result/%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AA%DB%8C/%3Ffoo%3D%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%26bar%3D%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86
```

But the result is not exactly true.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @MarcB The problem is I don't know about pattern of URL, because as I said this is dynamically and get by CURL from a web page, Maybe the Url is `http://www.example.com/result/رایانه` or `http://www.example.com/123/حسن/foo/` or everything!

Comment: @MarcB and I need just encode `رایانه` or `حسن` or.... for use in CURL.

Comment: you've already got the solution: `urlencode()`.

Comment: @MarcB I update question.

Comment: you can't encode the entire url. just encode the arabic parts, exactly as you had originally. `$url = "http://...." . urlencode($stuff_to_encode)`

Comment: @MarcB As I said, The URL fetch from another web pages, and I don't know about `$stuff_to_encode` var or any parameters... I thinks must split values in params URL for encode it.

Comment: @MarcB I find a solution! I post answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution:

```
$string = 'http://www.example.com/result/سوتی/?foo=علی&bar=حسن';
$string = urlencode($string);
echo str_replace(array('%3A', '%2F', '%3F', '%3D', '%26'), array(':', '/', '?', '=', '&'), $string);
```

Output:

```
http://www.example.com/result/%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AA%DB%8C/?foo=%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C&bar=%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86
```

It work with any URL and accept for use in CURL.